# Java EJB interfaces

Tags: java, ejb

Could anyone explain me how do the functions inside the HOME and REMOTE interfaces relate to the Bean object?

The interfaces are instanciated so that the functions are used. But the functions body rests only in the Bean object. What am I missing?

Comment: Home and remote interfaces? That's EJB 2.x. !! Why learn ancient stuff like that when EJB 3.x is more than 5 years old and much simpler???

Comment: @Sean: The remote interface is still required in EJB 3.1 if you want to support remote calls.

Comment: In his defence, he could be working on a legacy system, like me.  It burns us, preciousssssss.

Comment: @Michael that would be an interface with a `@Remote` annotation, as opposed to the much more complicated mechanism of having two separate interfaces in 2.x

Comment: Apart from legacy system, this could be some poor-quality tutorial from roseindia.net

Comment: @Sean: The annotation syntax is nicer, but `@Remote` does exactly the same as declaring a remote interface in a deployment descriptor. The home interface is a different matter, it became unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java EE container is dealing with those details for you.  It knows to find the bean implementation when a call is made to that interface.  It hides all the magic from you.

Answer (score 3):

The actual EJB instances will typically be instances of [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) that delegate calls to the bean's implementation class after doing their transaction-, clustering- and security-stuff.